# Dynamic string list and free() crashing application

Tags: c, free

I wrote a simple C code that should store a list of string  addresses (char*) inside a struct. The list is dynamic, so every time a new string is added, I reserve enough memory to store all the current string addresses plus the new one. Then I free the old buffer and assign the new one to the struct. The problem is that it crashes on free().

I am sure I am free()ing the exact address i got from calloc(), but still, it crashes.

here is the output:

> main(3618,0x7fff7a83f300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9902404bd0: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct StructNODE{
    char** stringlist;
    int stringcount;
    struct StructNODE* next;
} NODE;


void Addstring(NODE* node, const char* string)
{
    int currentBufferSize = node->stringcount * sizeof(char*);

    // make room for the current string list plus the new one
    char** addrList = (char**) calloc( 1, currentBufferSize );
    printf("malloc: %d bytes starting at 0x%X\n",currentBufferSize, addrList);

    // copy all current addresses to the new list
    memcpy(addrList, node->stringlist, currentBufferSize);

    printf("freeing mem at 0x%X\n",node->stringlist);
    free(node->stringlist);

    // Append the new address to the end of the address buffer
    addrList[node->stringcount] = (char*)string;

    //make the node point to the new buffer
    node->stringlist = addrList;

    // Increment the string number counter
    node->stringcount++;

}

void PrintStringlist(NODE* node)
{
    int i;
    for ( i=0; i < node->stringcount; i++)
    {
        printf("string %d: %s\n",i, node->stringlist[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    NODE* node = (NODE*) calloc(1 , sizeof(NODE));

    Addstring(node, "Lewis Skolnick");
    Addstring(node, "Gilbert Lowe");    
    Addstring(node, "Arnold Poindexter");       
    Addstring(node, "Harold Wormser");
    Addstring(node, "Booger");
    Addstring(node, "Takashi Toshiro");
    Addstring(node, "Lamar Latrelle");
    Addstring(node, "Judy");    

    PrintStringlist(node);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I overlooking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your buffer is too small - you forgot to add the space for an extra element. The fist function line should read:

```
    int currentBufferSize = (node->stringcount + 1) * sizeof(char*);
```

Comment: Thanks. That was exaclty the problem! I added the extra size on the calloc() call: 
    char** addrList = (char**) calloc( 1, currentBufferSize + sizeof(char*) );

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `calloc` is the following:

```
void* calloc (size_t num, size_t size);
```

So, assuming `stringcount` is the actual amount, you should call it with different arguments, eg

```
calloc(sizeof(char*), node->stringcount +1)
```

In any case there is another useful function in stdlib which is `realloc`, this allows you to resize directly the allocated memory without the need of copying all the data back by yourself or releasing the previous memory:

```
node->stringList = realloc(node->stringList, (node->stringcount+1)*sizeof(char*));
node->stringList[node->stringcount] = (char*)string;
```